# Electric Light - Old to New (Not working)

Tags: wiring

[image][image]I tried to change ceiling light which is based on old configuration and have 5 different .
2 are red (which are live wires). Refer attached picture (old).

In the new light - it require only two inputs which are live and neutral however it's not switched off which means circuit is not breaking up. Refer New picture.

Do I need to do anything different?

Comment: It would be _really_ helpful if you labeled the pictures as to which was old and which was new. Alternatively, you could reorganize your post to talk about the old, then have the "old" pic, then talk about the new and have the "new" pic. As it is, you're leaving it up to us to guess, and, well, that may not work out as well for you as you'd hope...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The terminal with 2 red wires is the 'always hot/live' coming from the circuit breaker. It's also delivering power *to* the light switch.
The plain black wire is neutral.
The other black wire with the red sleeve over it is the 'switched hot/live' coming *from* the light switch.

Connect your new light to the black(neutral) and red-sleeved black (switched hot/live) and it should work as expected.